# How to make ReSharper Unit Test Output window stop stripping line breaks

Tags: c#, resharper, xunit

I have ReSharper 10.0.2 installed.  When running unit tests (xUnit in my case) most line breaks get stripped from the UnitTestSession output window.  I use the `ITestOutputHelper` output.  When exporting via ReSharper UnitTestSession window to a text file all line breaks are present.

Is there a way to make the output window show text with line breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you experiencing [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-453661) (see second attached screenshot)? Could you maybe test the [current 10.1 EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+10.1+EAP) (in an experimental VS instance)?

Comment: OK. Then it should be fixed in version 2016.1 (you could verify that by testing the EAP).